# Create Keyboard Shortcuts for Arbitrary Operations for Highlighted File in File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, context-menu

Let's say that I have a file selected inside Windows file explorer.  Depending on the type of file, I may want to do different things with it, apart from simply opening it.  Is there any way that I can create keyboard shortcuts for different file types that perform different operations on that file (for example, such as open it with program apart from the default, running a script with the file-path of the highlighted file as a parameter, etc.)  Essentially, I'm referring to something along the lines of the context menu in terms of functionality, except being able to assign full control of keyboard shortcuts to these operations.

Can this be done in Windows 10, and if so, how?  Can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is a free open source software called 'AutoHotKey'. You can automate pretty much anything in Windows with it by writing a script for it.

For example:

F1 = Get file path of selected file, copy to clipboard, do what you want with it (scripting is needed here).

The site forum is rich with users both novice and expert answering to each others needs in matters of this regard.
https://autohotkey.com/board/

Download:
https://autohotkey.com/